# XSL Transformation array

Tags: xml, xslt

I do an XSL Transformation on a xml file and I get this XML

    `<data>
    <liste>
    <ch1>00209</ch1>
    <ch2>510484</ch1>
    <ch3>2</ch1>
    <ch4>1</ch1>
    </liste>
    </data>`

or 

    `<data>
    <liste>
    <ch1>00209</ch1>
    <ch2>510484</ch1>
    <ch3>2</ch1>
    <ch4>1</ch1>
    </liste>
    <liste>
    <ch1>00209</ch1>
    <ch2>510484</ch1>
    <ch3>2</ch1>
    <ch4>1</ch1>
    </liste>
    </data>`

after I transform to json and I get

```
"liste": {
                    "ch1": "00209",
                    "ch2": 510484,
                    "ch3": 2,
                    "ch4": 1
                }
```

if I have multiple node named liste I will have something like this (array)

```
"liste": [
    {
       "ch1": "00209",
                    "ch2": 510484,
                    "ch3": 2,
                    "ch4": 1
     },
      {
       "ch1": "00209",
                    "ch2": 510484,
                    "ch3": 2,
                    "ch4": 1
     }
]
```

But what I want to get is array forma even if I have one node liste

```
"liste": [ 
    {
                    "ch1": "00209",
                    "ch2": 510484,
                    "ch3": 2,
                    "ch4": 1
                }
    ]
```

Any Idea guys ?

Comment: Can you show your xml and xslt code?

Comment: Hello Nick I can't, this is simple XML containing one or multiple liste nodes.

Comment: The code you have shown in your question, is JSON, not XML. This means it is not really something you would use XSLT on, as XSLT is for processing XML, not JSON.

Comment: The XML that I get when I process the XSLT is that

Comment: <data>
    <liste>
        <ch1>00209</ch1>
        <ch2>510484</ch1>
        <ch3>2</ch1>
        <ch4>1</ch1>
     </liste>
</data>

 <data>
    <liste>
        <ch1>00209</ch1>
        <ch2>510484</ch1>
        <ch3>2</ch1>
        <ch4>1</ch1>
     </liste>
     <liste>
        <ch1>00209</ch1>
        <ch2>510484</ch1>
        <ch3>2</ch1>
        <ch4>1</ch1>
     </liste>
</data>

Comment: After I transform to json

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You can't get XML after "transform TO json"? Is the XML the input? Please show the XSL that you use as has already been suggested.

Comment: the process is 
xml --> xslt -->xml --> json

Comment: I show in my question the xml of step 3 and json of step 4

Comment: what I want is to have an array in my json all the time even if I have just one node, 
it is possible to do that ?

Comment: How are you converting xml -> json? Are you also using XSLT for that? If so, you should show that XSLT too. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a standard grouping problem. But you need to explain it much more clearly, and show your existing XSLT code; also explain whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.